# How to get Node-gyp working on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I'm just learning nodejs on windows.  It seems that the node-gyp package is incredibly painful to set up.  I've tried many guides online but I feel like I am playing a guessing game. The windows version is quite fresh, only a week or so old.

The official page (https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) says:

(trying to take the least complicated path)

> ```
> npm install -g node-gyp
>
> npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
> ```
>
> If the above didn't work" go to https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#compiling-native-addon-modules

---

If I just run **node-gyp**, I get

```
Cannot find module: 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js' ( etc ).
```

Even though that file exists.

I've even tried uninstalling node, clearing out `%appdata%` cache, etc, and removing other things.

---

If I try to install something dependent on node-gyp, I get:

```
..\src\ursaNative.cc(157): warning C4244: ( etc ) .. 

ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
```

---

I have spent many, many hours on this - I cannot believe how painful this is.

I have

- Installed the VS Tools (as above)
- Installed the C++ Compiler
- installed Build tools https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools&rel=15
- Tried setting the environment to VS2015 (and VS 2017)
- tried to follow many stack overflow fixes and posts. Surely there is a sure path to get this going.
- Various combinations of uninstalling / re-installing locally and globally.

Any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: What's the module dependent on `node-gyp` you're trying to use?

Comment: it seems that if I remove node_modules and package-lock.json file , then I run npm install --no-optional --msvs_version=2017 then it seems to work.  I'm just not sure if that is right!

Comment: The comment is not a correct answer to the original question @MartinThompson it probably means that node-gyp is not required for your project and it is only an optional dependancy.That been said you might not even use node-gyp ,lucky you!

Answer (score 18):

Got to this post trying to get a correct set-up for `node-gyp`, after upgrading `Node.js` from `v5.X` to `v12.X` by overriding previous installation, and upgrading `node-gyp`.

It seems fairly easy to miss some step when you already have a `Visual Studio` environment and one or more versions of `Python` installed.

I will try to synthesise here the steps that worked for me.

#### CONTEXT

Below the details as per configuration:

```
+-------+-----------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
|       | Component                   | Name        | Version                             |
+-------+-----------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
| (1)   | Platform                    | Windows 10  | NT 10.0.18362                       |
| (2)   | Target run-time environment | Node.js     | v12.16.1                            |
| (3)   | Packet Manager              | npm         | v6.13.4                             |
| (4)   | CLI Toolchain for compiling | node-gyp    | v6.0.1                              |
| (4.a) | Compiler Language           | Python      | v2.7.0                              |
| (4.b) | Project Builder             | MSBuild.exe | Microsoft (R) Build Engine for .NET |
|       |                             |             | version 16.2.32702+c4012a063        |
|       |                             |             | 16.200.19.32702                     |
+-------+-----------------------------+-------------+-------------------------------------+
```

### Guideline

You might have already walked through some of the steps outlined here. If you incurred in some issues, you may be able to identify at which stage something went wrong by reviewing the steps in detail:

**References**

1. `node-gyp` on GitHub: [README.md](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) (**G**enerate **Y**our **P**rojects)
2. [A Comprehensive Guide to Fixing Node-Gyp Issues on Windows](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/03/27/node-gyp-windows/)  (by  Joe Bustamante; March 27, 2019)
3. [Setting up None.js on Windows 10](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-windows-10-tutorial/) (by Ferenc Hámori; May 17, 2016)
4. [Using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#the-full-installer) (official documentation)

#### (1) Node.js

This guideline assumes that `git` is already installed in your machine (you will find the installer for Windows [here](https://gitforwindows.org/) anyways).

- Install `Node.js`: [download](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) the last LTS version for your platform (Windows Installer `.msi` should work)

To verify it is correctly installed, in a test folder, add a file `test.js` with this `javascript` code: `console.log("Node is installed!");`, and in a terminal run: `node test.js`. You should be prompted with `Node is installed!`.

#### (2) npm

- upgrade `npm` to the latest stable version using the `npm-windows-upgrade` package

Run as Administrator a PowerShell terminal:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm-windows-upgrade
```

You will be prompted to choose a version. The greatest available version among the options should be fine.

If you miss this package you might want to follow the instructions to install it by following the steps outlined in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade), which basically are to type the following in a PowerShell console running as Administrator:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install --global --production npm-windows-upgrade
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm-windows-upgrade
```

#### (3) Visual Studio

If you have `Visual Studio` already installed, you might skip this step, unless you wanted to also upgrade to the newest version.

In some posts, you might have read that you can achieve this step by simply using the following command line, after installing `node-gyp`:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools --vs2015
```

**However**, you could opt to achieve this by other means:

1. you may have already an installation of `Visual Studio` and just want to configure `node-gyp` to use it
2. you may prefer to do a separated installation of `Visual Studio` and later on configure `node-gyp` to use it

This is really up to you. At a later stage, in this guideline, we will walk through the steps to configure the `node-gyp` to use a specific `Visual Studio` version.

#### (4) Python

In the installation guideline for `node-gyp` ([GitHub official repo](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)) specifies which versions of `Python` are currently compatible with the latest `node-gyp` version on **Unix** and **macOS**. **However** it does **not** explain for **Windows** platforms (as at 1st of March 2020).

Although lack of documentation on this point, by having a look at other users' issues with this, it is fair to assume that on Windows platforms, `node-gyp` **is only supported for `Python` `v2.7.X`** ([reference](https://gist.github.com/jtrefry/fd0ea70a89e2c3b7779c)).

- [download Python 2.7.X here](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/): you can choose the bugfix release noted with an *available* link at the beginning.
- do a normal installation, and take note of the folder (preferably in a common folder where you will have all the python versions)

#### (5) node-gyp

Now it is the moment to correctly set up your `node-gyp` configuration.

If you haven not installed it as yet:

```
npm install --global node-gyp
```

**(5.1) Set the `Python` version**

According the documentation:

> If the NODE_GYP_FORCE_PYTHON environment variable is set to the path of a Python executable, it will be used instead of any of the other configured or builtin Python search paths. If it's not a compatible version, no further searching will be done.

1. identify the **full path** to the `C:\full_path\Python2.7.X\python.exe` file (by *full path* we mean all: the folder path **+** the target file `python.exe`)
2. go to *Control Panel* -> *System* and open *Advanced System Settings*, tab *Advanced*
3. at the bottom, click the button `Environmental Variables...`
4. a new panel pops up with two big sections: *User Variables* (only for the process owner), and *System Variables* (applicable to all the processes)
5. on the *System Variables*, create a `New` entry
6. name it `NODE_GYP_FORCE_PYTHON`, and as value use the **full path** to the python.exe file version `2.7.X`, and click `OK` and you are done

- for the variable to be available in the environment of your PowerShell terminal, you will need to close it and reopen a new terminal

7. you have just fixed the `python` version to be used for `node-gyp` in your system

Alternatively you can use the command line below:

```
npm config set python /path/to/executable/python
```

**(5.2) Set the `Visual Studio Build Tools` version**

This step should be fairly easy:

1. identify the **`year`** of your `Visual Studio` edition (i.e. 2015, 2017, 2019)
2. use it in the *year* part of the command line below:

```
npm config set msvs_version year
```

For example, if you want it to use the [MSBuild of 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019), use the command below:

```
npm config set msvs_version 2019
```

That must have done it.

#### (6) Testing node-gyp by creating a simple add-on in `C++`

**References**

1. [Mastering Node.js: Build robust and scalable real-time server-side web](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=LvNFDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA449#v=onepage&q&f=false) (by Sandro Pasquali & Kevin Faaborg, 2017, Packt Publishing): adapted example from here
2. [C++ Addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) (official documentation)
3. [V8 Embed](https://v8.dev/docs/embed) (explanation on how `V8` is embedded in `C++`)
4. [V8::FunctinonCallbackInfo Class Template](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-12.0/dd/d0d/classv8_1_1_function_callback_info.html) reference for `Node.js` `v12.0`

**Hands on work**

In a `test` folder, create `test\hello_module` subfolder with the following **empty** files:

- `hello_module\hello.cc` (our source `C++` native code)
- `hello_module\binding.gyp` (instruction file for `node-gyp`)
- `hello_module\index.js` (the wrapper)

In a terminal **initialise the package** by `npm ini`. You can choose the offered default value by just pressing `Enter` in all of them:

```
test\hello_module> npm ini
```

Now **fill the files in** with the contents specified below. Please, leave the `index.js` for the end, since we will be compiling before using it.

---

The **`hello.cc`** file content:

```cpp
#include <node.h>

namespace hello_module {
  using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
  using v8::Isolate;
  using v8::Local;
  using v8::Object;
  using v8::String;
  using v8::Value;
  
  void sayHello(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Hello World!"));
  }
  
  // the initialization function for hello_module
  void init(Local<Object> exports) {
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "sayHello", sayHello);
  }
  
  // node.h C++ macro to export the initialization function
  // (macros should not end by semicolon)
  NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, init)
}
```

- **UPDATE** (`2022-06-16`): at a suggestion of @Victor (see comments), *to **compile** with `Node.js 14` and `MSVC 2017`* at line 13, a call to `ToLocalChecked()` should be performed as well:

```
args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Hello World!").ToLocalChecked())
```

The **`binding.gyp`** file content:

```json
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "hello",
      "sources": [ "hello.cc" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

You can leave the `index.js` file for the end.

Now, let's **build the project**:

```
test\hello_module> node-gyp configure
 gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
 gyp info using node-gyp@6.1.0
 gyp info using node@12.16.1 | win32 | x64
 gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.0 found at "C:\python\2.7.0\python.exe"
 gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.2.29123.88) found at:
 gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community"
 # .. omited .. #
 gyp info ok
```

The `test\hello_module\build` folder should have been created with the basic project files to compile a `C++` solution (this is what `node-gyp` basically aims to: that you can use any `C++` compiler without having to use the `GUI`; in this case `Visual Studio`).

Now, let's **build the addon**:

```
test\hello_module> node-gyp build
```

At the end of both commands you should read `gyp info ok` to know that everything was okay (you might not see it on a PowerShell terminal because of the blue background; if so, you can edit the *Properties* of the window and change *Screen Background* to **black**).

This command should have created the `test\hello_module\build\Release` folder with the `hello.node` file.

**Notes**:

1. **If everything went `ok`**, you are done in verifying your `node-gyp` installation: **it works!**

- once you got this simple add-on to work, if you are still having issues with some package(s), that might be related to that package alone, or some of its dependencies, but your `node` or `node-gyp` configuration are okay

2. if you encountered problems during the build, you might use the documentation to troubleshoot the source of the problem, or open a new post specifying which the errors you encountered are, and someone might be able to help

#### (7) Wrap and use the add-on in `C++`

This is an extra step. As you might have got here, why leaving it like this?

Now let's write the wrapper **`hello_module\index.js`** file:

```js
const helloAddon = require('./build/Release/hello.node');
module.exports = helloAddon;
```

And in the `test` folder, create the **`test\hello_world.js`** file that uses our addon:

```js
const {sayHello} = require('./hello_module');
console.log(sayHello())
```

And in the terminal:

```
test> node hello_world.js
```

You should see `Hello World!` prompted on the screen.

Hope this helps anyone having issues to identify where exactly the configuration of `node-gyp` failed to meet requirements.

Comment: After 3 days of R&d, I reached to this answer and finally, it worked for me, is development with windows that hard or only I am struggling with it. :)

Comment: To compile with Node.js 14 and MSVC 2017, I've changed line 13 of hello.cc to `args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Hello World!").ToLocalChecked());` (added `.ToLocalChecked()`)

Comment: this is such a useful answer!! However i'm getting intellisense warnings on "Set" in `args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "Hello World!"));"` =  `no instance of overloaded function "v8::ReturnValue<T>::Set [with T=v8::Value]" matches the argument list  C/C++(304)`   and `node-gyp build` error:   `test\hello_module\hello.cc(13,75): error C2665: 'v8::ReturnValue<T>::Set': none of the 4 overloads could convert all the argument types \test\hello_module\build\hello.vcxproj]`

Comment: Wow.  Amazing answer, and now I realize I am NEVER EVER going to install anything in node that requires being built.  This is WAY too much work, especially when usually the reason I find packages that require being built is to try to find workarounds to other issues that windows causes.

Comment: 2022. The answer above though beautiful, it did not work for me unfortunately. A few extra similar steps required for me (with Python 3.X): https://stackoverflow.com/a/70799513/3625240

Answer (score 6):

your node-gyp module is initialised from the NPM but there is a fair chance that its correct path is not added to the environment variables in your system, Just add it to the system variables. Check the path variable if it has "**C://Users/abc/AppData/Roaming/npm**" if not, Please add it.

Also check if python is added to your environment variable.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This was raised in issue  1463.  It seems to be a bug from following the docs instructions for node-gyp install -g  and   npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

I found a very simple solution.

If node_gyp is on your disk as it should be, like so:
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"

But an error message expects this:
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"

You simply add an extra node_modules folder beneath "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\"

Then you copy the entire existing \node-gyp folder into the new \node_modules\node_modules folder.

You have a redundant node-gyp folder, but the configure and build steps will now work as expected.

At least that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the Visual Studio Code installer and on MSBuild Tools, select the "More" drop down and click repair

> [image: repair]

.

Answer (score 0):

I found this via search engine today. I'm a NPM module author and I depend on a module with depends on node-gyp. The npm dependency resolution was installing an ancient versions of node-gyp (3.8), so I resolved this for our package (and users) by declaring an explicit dependency on node-gyp ^8. Bonus: this fixes CI tests on GitHub workflows, which were broken for us since windows-latest was switched to windows server 2022, around March 6th, 2022.

Answer (score -2):

You have to install `windows-build-tools` as it says in README https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#option-1

Comment: Thanks for your comment , but as I said in the post I have tried that.