# node-gyp configure got "gyp ERR! find VS"

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, node-gyp

I am trying to start about node c/c++ add-on. the `node-gyp` command got error

I have installed vs2019, my command is

```
node-gyp configure --msvs_version=2019
```

the verbose output is

```
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@5.0.3
gyp info using node@10.16.0 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.15 found at "C:\Users\seact\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2019
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - found in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"
gyp ERR! find VS - could not find MSBuild in registry for this version
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (D:\Program Files\node-win-x64\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at findVisualStudio2013 (D:\Program Files\node-win-x64\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (D:\Program Files\node-win-x64\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:344:14)       
gyp ERR! stack     at findVisualStudio2015 (D:\Program Files\node-win-x64\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at regSearchKeys (D:\Program Files\node-win-x64\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:377:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at regGetValue (D:\Program Files\node-win-x64\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at D:\Program Files\node-win-x64\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:301:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "D:\\Program Files\\node-win-x64\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\node-win-x64\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--msvs_version=2019"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Projects\learn_node_ext
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: In my case, *Downgrading the node version* from `18` to `16` resolved the problem!

Answer (score 57):

You do not have to install Visual Studio, just install the windows build tools:

1. run CMD as Admin
2. run `npm install --g --production windows-build-tools`

This should fix that.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/31D1U.png]

Comment: 2021 and `npm install --g --production windows-build-tools` install python 2.7? Kidding me? :/

Comment: this is no longer working. official node.js installer for windows (node 16) now has the option to install build tools (python and visual studio), this is also described on top of the repo: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools

Comment: This doesn't work for me and the following error happens  Downloading installers failed. Error: TypeError: 'process.env' only accepts a configurable, writable, and enumerable data descriptor

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 57):

There are 2 aspects to this error. Now in 2022, if you have installed Visual Studio 2022, even after installing `Desktop development with C++` or the build tools it still wont work.

Few things you need to do even after installation.
`npm config get python` should be set to Python 3.x
--> `npm config set python C:\Python310\python.exe`

`npm config get msvs_version` should be using 2022
--> `npm config set msvs_version 2022 --global`

Additionally you can set
`npm config set msbuild_path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"`

your `VCINSTALLDIR` ENV variable should be set to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC`

Also, additionally add user environment variable `GYP_MSVS_VERSION`= 2022 (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318249/4271117))

[image: VCINSTALLDIR]

Before `npm install` delete node_modules folder from your root folder along with package-lock.json and then re ran `npm install`.

In some case it still wont work, then you can follow the additional steps, visit the folder of your Node.js exe installation, should be same even for an nvm node version; https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/docs/Updating-npm-bundled-node-gyp.md

```
cd "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
cd node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script

npm install node-gyp@latest
```

Comment: Most of your code is very helpful.
There is only one line of code that should be corrected. You should set `VCINSTALLDIR ` as `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC` ( must add the "\VC" ).

Comment: Thanks @Adiaos for suggesting edits and Robin for copying it.

Comment: Does the python setting have to be global as well?

Comment: @Poikilos yes if you open Terminal on windows and type `python --version` it should print

Comment: This is very close, but I had to add one last piece - GYP_MSVS_VERSION. see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75318249/4271117) below

Comment: Brilliant! Last line saved me thanks

Comment: I have NodeJS version 20 installed and I'm getting the error: "npm ERR! `msbuild_path` is not a valid npm option" while running your line.

Answer (score 18):

Open your Visual Studio & then in 'search box' search `VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools`  and install then search `Desktop development with C++` install it. Hope this helps.

Comment: This worked for me. Also, 'VS 2019 C++ x64/86 build tools' had multiple versions. I picked up the highest version number.

Comment: I picked latest version of VS 2022 C++ x64/86 build tools

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Chocolatey, install the following:

```
choco install visualstudio2019buildtools visualstudio2019-workload-vctools
```

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm. No need to download VS.

Answer (score 8):

It is because the C++ build tools are not installed. It can be solved by installing `VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools` in Visual Studio installer:

[image: looks like this]

Answer (score 5):

Downloading the latest Visual Studio build Tools

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2019

and running the following command in the 'Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools' Directory

```
npm install --g --production windows-build-tools
```

and Installing node-gyp in the current directory

```
npm install node-gyp
```

Worked For me on Windows 10

for more, please visite the [official node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) installation guide

Answer (score 4):

Your powershell is running probably in constrained mode.
See this thread: [how to change PowerShell mode to fulllanguage mode from constrained mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032747/how-to-change-powershell-mode-to-fulllanguage-mode-from-constrained-mode)

Answer (score 2):

I had to set python path for npm even though I had python on my PATH.

```
npm config set python /path/to/executable/python
```

then try `npm install` again

Answer (score 2):

It should be a npm package bug of windows-build-tools.

Step 1: Be sure you installed Visual Studio Code

Step 2: Search %temp% under window search bar (Copy `%temp%` then press windows button + Ctrl V)

[image]

Step 3: Create 'dd_client_.log.txt' and enter 'Closing installer. Return code: 3010.'

[image]

Now you should be able to finish the whole process with `npm install --global windows-build-tools`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solution that worked for me was to install latest Visual Studio Build Tools and then execute following command, taken from node-gyp installation instructions [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows):

`npm config set msvs_version 2017`

Comment: latest node version does not accept setting it in cmd. Use `npm config edit` instead and write `msvs_version 2017`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running `'npm install'`, run `'npm update'` directly in the folder. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue faced by me with VS 2022 community edition, node 15.x, python 3.10

```
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
```

Issue was due to non-compatible Node version 15.x.x to gyp
and, successfully resolved with downgrading node to 14.17.3 version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** Installing the latest LTS version of Node.js via Windows Installer worked for me somehow. [Latest LTS Version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

[image: Nodejs Latest LTS Version]

I tried all the answers from this thread and some other articles as well but nothing was working for me. After spending 6+ hours on this issue, I saw this note on `Windows-Build-Tools` [Github](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools) page.

> Please note that the official Node.js for Windows installer can now automatically install the required tools. That's likely a much better option than the module listed here (windows-build-tools).

So I installed the latest LTS version of Node.js via Windows Installer from [Node js website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) as shown in the above image and it worked somehow.

Answer (score 1):

My working environment: Visual Studio Enterprise 2022, Python 3.11, and Node v18.13.0. I did everything according to [steel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70799513/4271117), but still got errors. Looks like `npm config set msvs_version 2022 --global` doesn't help.

I finally got it working by [adding an Environment Variable](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/commit/a8d441a0a2db8406e1da63559bcf31b7d293b5e1) - `GYP_MSVS_VERSION` and setting it to 2022.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. After quickly scanning the logs, I could see that the error code was 1.
Error code 1 (in npm) usually occurs because of version mismatch between modules/packages.

When I run the command `npm update --legacy-peer-deps` the problem was resolved.

Most probably a particular package is causing the issue, so although the error raised by `node-gyp` **might** appear to be confusing, when actually it may happen because of incompatibility due to updated node or some other major package version with some other package. So, do try to add `--legacy-peer-deps` flag with the `npm update`

Answer (score 0):

1. [Download Visual Studio Community Edition](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=16)
2. Run the executable
3. Choose the options as below.

[image]

and it should solve the issue.

Comment: Just selecting `Desktop development with C++` works.

Answer (score 0):

In case if someone still has the visual studio installation required error after going through all the steps mentioned above. I had this issue when I was trying to run an electron application. The solution for my issue was simply adding the visual studio to the environment variables after going through all the above steps.

To set the path run the following command on cmd (if possible as admin):

setx VCTargetsPath “C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\15.0"

Note: the path for my visual studio was as in the above. you may have to change it according to your installation.

The software versions I was using are as follows:
nodejs : 14.17.0
OS : windows10 64-bit
Python : 2.7.15 (installed default with node js)
Visual studio : community edition 2019

some of the other things to check is to make sure the python version, msvs_version are set to the correct versions in the npm config.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue after upgrading to latest node LTS version. This did the trick for me:

1. removed node_modules folder
2. removed package-lock.json file
3. `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

It took me a day and a half to resolve this in October 2023. On a high level, I had to perform three steps:

1. Install Visual Studio 2019 **build-tools** through Chocolatey (although I am using Visual Studio 2022)
2. **Update** the configuration through **yarn** package manager
3. **Downgrade NodeJS** to match the version supported by node-sass

Now, I will explain the steps in more detail.

### 1st Step - Build tools 2019

```
choco install visualstudio2019buildtools visualstudio2019-workload-vctools
```

### 2nd Step - Yarn configurations

Set the correct path to you Python executable:

```
yarn config set python C:\Python310\python.exe
```

Set the msvs_version:

```
yarn config set msvs_version 2019 --global
```

Set msbuild_path:

```
yarn config set msbuild_path "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Msbuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
```

Your **VCINSTALLDIR** ENV variable should be set to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC`

Add *user* Environment variable **GYP_MSVS_VERSION= 2019**

[image]

Additionally, you might want to upgrade `node-gyp`, but it wasn't the problem in my case:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\nodejs"
cd node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\run-script
npm install node-gyp@latest
```

Delete the `node_modules` folder from your project folder, and then run `yarn install`

### 3rd Step - Downgrading NodeJS

From the beginning, the error was pointing to the `node-sass` package I was using without specifying the issue. Turned out it was a version incompatibility.

[image]

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass?activeTab=readme

In my case, I simply deleted the latest NodeJS package and installed a new particular version that was compatible with my version of `node-sass`.

```
choco uninstall nodejs@latest
choco install nodejs-18.0.0
```

If you're using `npm`, just change the word yarn to **npm** in all the commands. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to install VS 2017 Build Tools (in addition to VS 2022 Build Tools) - but for 2017 build tools I ONLY needed the "Visual C++ build tools" (with VC++ 2017 and Visual C++ 2017 Build Tools core features and  Redistributable Update)

Now VS 2022 does not seem to have the "Visual C++ Build Tools", although it does have "Desktop development with C++". 3 Days of my life gone.

Answer (score -1):

on my computer works with the next commands

```
npm install --g --production windows-build-tools
npm install node-gyp
npm audit fix
npm install node-phpass
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem before, thanks [C. Szabo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63184664/723366).

node-gyp use Powershell script to find Visual Studio. You should check

```
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode
```

in Powershell. If it return 'ConstrainedLanguage', node-gyp will fail to find Visual Studio. Change `_PSLockdownPolicy` in register can fix this problem, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57032893/723366). (Don't forget to reboot Windows)

Answer (score -1):

I also encountered this error. After trying all the suggestions I could find and spending 2 days trying to resolve it, I finally found out the reason it wasn't working for me was that in my build environment I didn't have **ProgramData env variable defined**. After adding "ProgramData": "C:\ProgramData" everything started working like a charm.

When this env var is not defined, for whatever reason, `query2.EnumAllInstances()` in Find-VisualStudio.cs returns empty enumeration.

Hopefully this will be useful for someone as well.

Answer (score -1):

npm install --g --production windows-build-tools

Answer (score -2):

My friend creates the project and her ***node/npm versions*** are not compatible with mine.
So I try to upgrade my npm versions only. It's solved the problem.

But some of the dependencies are not working. So I update the node versions, as along with the npm version, will update. It solved almost all problems and errors.

You should find the correct compatible version of node and npm. [Here you can find the node version and compatible npm version.](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)

### `Make sure to check your npm version and node versions are compatible.`