# Facing error in installing shards-react using npm

Tags: reactjs, npm-install

When I am trying to install shards-react using `npm i shards-react` I am getting the error below:-

```
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.18.1: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410     
npm WARN deprecated iltorb@2.4.5: The zlib module provides APIs for brotli compression/decompression starting with Node.js v10.16.0, please use it over iltorb

> iltorb@2.4.5 install E:\Web Development\PUNEET PUGALIA\Marketplace-tokuten\node_modules\iltorb
> node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild

info looking for cached prebuild @ C:\Users\Themachilles\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_prebuilds\ee308d-iltorb-v2.4.5-node-v83-win32-x64.tar.gz
http request GET https://github.com/nstepien/iltorb/releases/download/v2.4.5/iltorb-v2.4.5-node-v83-win32-x64.tar.gz
http 404 https://github.com/nstepien/iltorb/releases/download/v2.4.5/iltorb-v2.4.5-node-v83-win32-x64.tar.gz
WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=14.16.0 runtime=node arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)

E:\Web Development\PUNEET PUGALIA\Marketplace-tokuten\node_modules\iltorb>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Themachilles\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\Themachilles\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) 
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\Themachilles\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Themachilles\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\Themachilles\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Themachilles\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Themachilles\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Themachilles\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\Themachilles\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.16.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Themachilles\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v14.16.0\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\Web Development\PUNEET PUGALIA\Marketplace-tokuten\node_modules\iltorb
gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.1 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! iltorb@2.4.5 install: `node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the iltorb@2.4.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Themachilles\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-19T14_04_18_940Z-debug.log
```

Please help about how can I resolve it and how can I intsall shards-react. I am mostly getting error with installing iltorb. But when I am using zlib module still then its not installing as well I am getting the same error there as well.

Comment: not sure if this might help,
but look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541402/node-gyp-configure-got-gyp-err-find-vs/63311413#63311413).

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in package.json to:

"shards-react": "darizabalo/shards-react#master",

or

Steps to resolve:

1. Install Visual Studio Community
2. After installation run Visual Studio Installer
3. Select Modify option on your current Visual Studio Installation
4. Select and install Desktop Develmopment with C++ Workload with default options
5. After that npm i shards-react works with no problems