# Getting a error when installing TRUFFLE on windows

Tags: blockchain, solidity, truffle

I have tried installing truffle on windows powershell with Execution Policy set to "ByPass".

And installing a older version but noting has worked any help is appreciated.

I have node v16.13.0. And have not had any problems before with installing packages.

As well I have the latest version of Virtual studio code.

```
 npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\boxin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\secp256k1
    npm ERR! command failed
    npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
    npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
    npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
    npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64
    npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.0 found at "C:\Users\boxin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)     
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\boxin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\node_modules\ganache\node_modules\secp256k1
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.2.0
    npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: try to with specific old version.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fix the problem by uninstalling node.js and reinstall in it. And when i installed node, I checked the box that shows up that installs extra build tools.

Answer (score -1):

Hello did u try `npm install --g --production windows-build-tools`

Similar problem -> [node-gyp configure got "gyp ERR! find VS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541402/node-gyp-configure-got-gyp-err-find-vs)

Lot of ppl had similiar issue and this command helped

If nothing will help i can recommend u https://remix.ethereum.org/ its online IDE that simulate everything. (I have good experience with it on Ether and solidity)

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work but thanks for the time.