# Gyp ERR! when running Yarn install on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2017, node-gyp

I have `node` installed via [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). I am running `yarn` on a nodejs project on windows 10 and encounter this error

```
> gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2015
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2022 (17.2.32616.157) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v143
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.19041.0
gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.32602.291) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - missing any VC++ toolset
gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2017 (15.9.28307.2019) found at:
gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v141
gyp ERR! find VS - found Windows SDK: 10.0.17763.0
gyp ERR! find VS - msvs_version does not match this version
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
gyp ERR! find VS - "2022"
gyp ERR! find VS - "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
gyp ERR! find VS - "2017"
gyp ERR! find VS - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools"
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
```

I have tried these:

- [How can I solve error gypgyp ERR!ERR! find VSfind VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57879150/how-can-i-solve-error-gypgyp-errerr-find-vsfind-vs-msvs-version-not-set-from-c) to install Visual Studio Community 2022, Visual Build Tools 2017 and 2019.
- Run `npm install --global windows-build-tools@4.0.0` as Admin right

Both don't solve the problem. Could anyone help with this? Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541402/node-gyp-configure-got-gyp-err-find-vs