# Angular setup issues

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am trying to setup Angular project on my windows machine and getting below error on NPM install.

1. I cloned the existing angular project.
2. Installed angular cli as per project.
3. Setup paths in environment variables.
4. Installed Python and made its path global

Versions: I have  @angular/cli@12.2.8, python: 3.10, node: v16.13.2,updated vscode, setup the paths on env variable.

````
6455 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\index.js:64:27)
6455 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
6455 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
6455 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
6456 verbose pkgid fibers@5.0.0
6457 verbose cwd C:\workspaces\angular
6458 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
6459 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
6460 verbose node v16.13.2
6461 verbose npm  v8.1.2
6462 error code 1
6463 error path C:\workspaces\angular\node_modules\fibers
6464 error command failed
6465 error command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node build.js || nodejs build.js
6466 error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
6466 error gyp info using node-gyp@8.3.0
6466 error gyp info using node@16.13.2 | win32 | x64
6466 error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.6 found at "C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe"
6466 error gyp ERR! find VS
6466 error gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
6466 error gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
6466 error gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer, try re-running with '--loglevel silly' for more details
6466 error gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
6466 error gyp ERR! find VS - not found
6466 error gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
6466 error gyp ERR! find VS
6466 error gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
6466 error gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
6466 error gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
6466 error gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
6466 error gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
6466 error gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
6466 error gyp ERR! find VS
6466 error gyp ERR! configure error
6466 error gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
6466 error gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
6466 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
6466 error gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
6466 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
6466 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
6466 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
6466 error gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
6466 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:404:5)
6466 error gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
6466 error gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1064:16)
6466 error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19044
6466 error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
6466 error gyp ERR! cwd C:\workspaces\angular\node_modules\fibers
6466 error gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.2
6466 error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.3.0
6466 error gyp ERR! not ok
6466 error node-gyp exited with code: 1
6466 error Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
6466 error would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
6466 error build environment--
6466 error Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
6466 error Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
6466 error RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`
6466 error Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
6466 error 'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
6466 error operable program or batch file.
6467 verbose exit 1```
````

Comment: The error message says `gyp` could not find Visual Studio 2017 or 2015. You will need to install one of them plus the "Desktop development with C++" workload. More info at [`node-gyp` on GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows). This is all available in the error message.

Comment: Here's the same question with other resolutions: [node-gyp configure got "gyp ERR! find VS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541402/node-gyp-configure-got-gyp-err-find-vs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node-gyp configure got "gyp ERR! find VS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541402/node-gyp-configure-got-gyp-err-find-vs)

Comment: didn't help me , seems all the answers are outdated