# A want install npm install command and i got these 'react'

Tags: reactjs, npm, installation, frontend

this is the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgkwD.jpg

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node-gyp configure got "gyp ERR! find VS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541402/node-gyp-configure-got-gyp-err-find-vs)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.