# Error related to Visual Studio running electron

Tags: electron

i want to run my app on windows but it says:

✔ Checking your system
✔ Locating application
✔ Loading configuration
✖ Preparing native dependencies: 0 / 1
› node-gyp failed to rebuild 'C:\Users\aafz1\OneDrive\Desktop\myapp\node_modules\active-win'
◼ Running generateAssets hook

› Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\aafz1\OneDrive\Desktop\myapp\node…

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: node-gyp failed to rebuild 'C:\Users\aafz1\OneDrive\Desktop\myapp\node_modules\active-win'
at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\aafz1\OneDrive\Desktop\myapp\node_modules@electron\rebuild\lib\module-type\node-gyp\node-gyp.js:118:24)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)

i don't know what to do!

i also installed vsc but don't know what to do next!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node-gyp configure got "gyp ERR! find VS"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57541402/node-gyp-configure-got-gyp-err-find-vs)